# How can i register a global custom editor in Spring-MVC?

Tags: spring, data-binding, spring-mvc

I use the following custom editor in MANY Spring-MVC controllers according to:

A controller

```
binder.registerCustomEditor(BigDecimal.class, new CustomNumberEditor(BigDecimal.class, NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("pt", "BR"), true));
```

Other controller

```
binder.registerCustomEditor(BigDecimal.class, new CustomNumberEditor(BigDecimal.class, NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("pt", "BR"), true));
```

Another controller

```
binder.registerCustomEditor(BigDecimal.class, new CustomNumberEditor(BigDecimal.class, NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("pt", "BR"), true));
```

Notice the same custom editor registered

Question: how can i set up a global custom editor like this one in order to avoid set up each controller ?

regards,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to declare it in your application context:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer">
  <property name="customEditors"><map>
    <entry key="java.math.BigDecimal">
      <bean class="org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor">
      ... <!-- specify constructor-args here -->
      </bean>
    </entry>
  </map></property>
</bean>
```

Details are [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/validation.html#beans-beans-conversion-customeditor-registration)

Comment: Does it override default Spring PropertyEditors ?

Comment: Yes. Page I linked to above specifically states that (Table 5.2. Built-in PropertyEditors)

Comment: The customEditors property is deprecated, and will be removed in Spring 3 (according to the javadoc). You should use the PropertyEditorRegistrars property instead.

Comment: @skaffman - you're right, thanks. It's not actually marked as deprecated (it only says so in the comment), so I've never noticed that. `propertyEditorRegistrars` is the way to go.

Comment: @skaffman it's actually support for `PropertyEditor` that's deprecated, not the property/method itself. Docs for 3.0+ suggest they didn't remove it after all (but it's still deprecated)

Answer (score 32):

Starting Spring 3.2, you can use [@ControllerAdvice](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html) instead of using  @ExceptionHandler, @InitBinder, and @ModelAttribute in each Controller. They will be applied to all @Controller beans.

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.InitBinder;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;

@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalBindingInitializer {
  @InitBinder
  public void registerCustomEditors(WebDataBinder binder, WebRequest request) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(BigDecimal.class, new  CustomNumberEditor(BigDecimal.class, NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("pt", "BR"), true));
  }
}
```

If you had started out with Spring Roo generated code, or limit the annotations scanned by component-scan using include-filter, then add the required filter in webmvc-config.xml

```
<!-- The controllers are autodetected POJOs labeled with the @Controller annotation. -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.sensei.encore.maininterface" use-default-filters="false">
  <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
  <!-- ADD THE BELOW LINE -->
  <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice" type="annotation"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

Answer (score 13):

If you use a annotation based controller (Spring 2.5+), you can use a WebBindingInitializer to register global property editors. Something like

```
public class GlobalBindingInitializer implements WebBindingInitializer {

    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder, WebRequest request) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"), true));
    }

}
```

So in your web application context file, declare

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="webBindingInitializer">
        <bean class="GlobalBindingInitializer"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This way all annotation based controller can use any property editor declared in GlobalBindingInitializer.

Comment: For me, the class code was a big help, but adding it via the web app context file caused odd problems. I instead annotated the class with ControllerAdvice and the method with InitBinder and it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative option. Instead of @ControllerAdvice, you can create abstract class, inherited by your controllers:

```
public abstract class BaseController {
    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        // Replace empty strings with nulls for submitted form fields.
        binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringTrimmerEditor(true));
    }
}
```