# Questions about property editor (customEditor) not being applied?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring mvc 3 and I'd like to format a field.
Per a suggestion I'd like to move it to a property editor.

However it doesn't seem to be applied.
I did:

```
@InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, "mobileNumber", new MobileNumberEditor(false));
    }
```

Where mobileNumber is a variable of my User object.
I've also tried user.mobileNumber but that doesn't seem to work either?

I could probably register (User.class,new UserEditor(false)) but that seems to be a bit of a roundabout way.

Comment: see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268021/how-can-i-register-a-global-custom-editor-in-spring-mvc

Comment: No, it doesn't. What those are doing is registring a type. What I'm trying to do is to register a property of a type.

Comment: It should work if you have (@ModelAttribute User user) as a param in the controller and a String property called mobileNumber in the User object. Are you sure it is not called. Try setting a breakpoint in the setAsText() and getAsText() methods of the editor to see if they are invoked in debug mode.

Comment: Mmh, does it have to be a modelattribute? It's currently a request attribute.

Comment: I think it has to be @ModelAttribute at least in the way you register the custom editor, because you add the param "mobileNumber" so it will only bind the editor to the property mobileNumber of the object. I have never tried it with a @RequestParam. You can try it but tehn in case it would work it should be a @RequestParam String mobileNumber as a param and in the binder it would be binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class,new MobileNumberEditor(false)); (without specifying the field). But this (in case it would work with RequestParam) it would apply the editor to ever String field.

Comment: With RequestParam I know you can use Conversion Service in Spring 3 if that helps: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert