# Set date format for an input text using Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

How can I set the format for a [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) in a text field with Spring MVC?

I'm using the Spring Form tag library and the `input` tag.

What I get now is something like this `Mon May 28 11:09:28 CEST 2012`.

I'd like to show the date in `dd/MM/yyyy` format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

register a date editor in yr controller :

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateEditor());
}
```

and then the data editor itself can look like this :

```
public class LocalDateEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport{

 @Override
 public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException{
   setValue(Joda.getLocalDateFromddMMMyyyy(text));
 }

 @Override
 public String getAsText() throws IllegalArgumentException {
   return Joda.getStringFromLocalDate((LocalDate) getValue());
 }
}
```

I am using my own abstract utility class (Joda) for parsing dates, in fact LocalDates from [Joda Datetime library](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) - recommended as the standard java date/calendar is an abomination, imho. But you should get the idea. Also, you can register a global editor, so you don't have to do it each controller (I can't remember how).

Comment: Thank you! that's definitely better than my solution.

Comment: @davioooh Spring 3.0 + ? This is relevant chapter I think http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html "using propertyregistars" shows how to do globally

Comment: Yes, I'm using Spring 3.1, but I'm still new to it... (and to Spring Framework in general...)

Comment: here how to set a global editor: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1268021/1061499 Very helpful!

Answer (score 8):

Done! I just added this method to my controller class:

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(
            dateFormat, false));
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to format all your dates without having to repeat the same code in every Controller, you can create a **global InitBinder** in a class annotated with [**@ControllerAdvice**](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html) annotation.

## Steps

**1.** Create a DateEditor class that will format your dates, like this:

```
    public class DateEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {
     
    public void setAsText(String value) {
      try {
        setValue(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(value));
      } catch(ParseException e) {
        setValue(null);
      }
    }

    public String getAsText() {
      String s = "";
      if (getValue() != null) {
         s = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format((Date) getValue());
      }
      return s;
    }
```

**2.** Create a class annotated with @ControllerAdvice (I called it GlobalBindingInitializer):

```
    @ControllerAdvice
    public class GlobalBindingInitializer {
     
     /* Initialize a global InitBinder for dates instead of cloning its code in every Controller */
     
      @InitBinder
      public void binder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new DateEditor());
      }
    }
```

**3.** In your Spring MVC configuration file (for example webmvc-config.xml) add the lines that allow Spring to scan the package in which you created your GlobalBindingInitializer class. For example, if you created GlobalBindingInitializer in the org.example.common package:

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.example.common" />
```

Finished!

**Sources:**

- [Keenformatics - How To create a global InitBinder in Spring with @ControllerAdvice](https://www.keenformatics.com/how-to-create-global-initbinder-in-spring/) (my blog)
- [Spring Framework 3.2.4 - Annotation Type ControllerAdvice](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html)
- [Spring Framework API 2.5 - Annotation Type InitBinder](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/InitBinder.html)
- Personal experience