# WebDataBinder custom date editor doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to register custom date editor in spring's MVC WebDataBinder to make spring parse my custom date fomat (to be exact, it's ISO format).
I succeded with that by implementing CustomWebBindingInitializer.

```
 public static class CustomWebBindingInitializer implements WebBindingInitializer {

    @Override
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder webDataBinder, WebRequest webRequest) {
        CustomDateEditor dateEditor = new CustomDateEditor(new ISODateFormat(), true);
        webDataBinder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, dateEditor);
    }
}
```

Spring is using my editor and parses date successfully , but nontheless date field doesn't get bound and I get following error for the request:

```
"org.springframework.validation.BindException",,"defaultMessage":"Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Date] for property 'from'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not parse date: Unparseable date: \"2016-08-01T10:35:04.126Z\""
```

What's worth noting:
when I use default spring's format MM/DD/YYYY with **my custom editor** I get the same error, which means that spring is using my editor instead of default one.

when I use **default spring's parser** with format MM/DD/YYYY everything works and date gets bound, which is obvious of course.

Anyone had the same issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Add format to `registerCustomEditor` and try :

```
 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("Required format");
 webDataBinder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, dateEditor, new CustomDateEditor(format, true));
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved by using PropertyEditorSupport instead of CustomDateEditor as in
[Set date format for an input text using Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10785107/set-date-format-for-an-input-text-using-spring-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

Create `SimpleDateFormat` with required date format like `"yyyy-MM-dd"`

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Register `CustomDateEditor` with required `dateForat`

```
binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, false));
```